# How to address raycast failures due to tiny holes in a mesh?

Tags: unity, raycasting, mesh

**Problem:**

I have a racing circuit that is made out of tiles, each of which is made out of 2 triangles. I need to know over which tile my craft is hovering on; but since there are tiny holes between some of the tiles, casting a ray fails sometimes.

Note: fixing the mesh from within a 3D modeler **is not** an option.

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a robust method for approaching this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean there are tiny holes in the mesh? From a plane like this, the only way I could think of having a hole in the mesh was if someone added a plane/mesh and scooted it over to line up with another mesh, without actually joining them. I believe fixing it is probably the best option, but if you insist, perhaps checking from +- 1 of various locations until you get a result.

Comment: If ray casting failed you are not on top of a tile. If you are always on top of a tile there are no holes. Conclusion: It is not the mesh you want to ray cast against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DMGregory has pointed out in the comment, you can use [SphereCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) instead. A spherecast works a lot like a raycast, only that instead of checking for hits in a single line, it has a 'radius' parameter which defines the size of the sphere, effectively making it behave like a thick ray.

Example:

```
RaycastHit hit;

if(Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.1f, Vector3.down, out hit)){
    ...
}
```

You can easily change your code by replacing `Physics.Raycast` with `Physics.SphereCast`, and passing a float value after the `origin` parameter depending on how big the holes are.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to use two or more raycasts that are placed close together but not in the same position. That way if one misses due to a mesh seam, the other should hit.

Comment: A spherecast will have a similar effect — it's basically a "thick ray" so it won't squeeze through tiny gaps as easily.